# Column Sizing Example for Bootstrap Confusion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to figure out why the input is sized so small when example said `col-xs-<number>`. From my understanding of Bootstrap, doesn't that mean when the screen size meets the criteria it'll adjust accordingly and anything greater would automatically take up the whole 12 columns. Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the example on the documentation: https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/css/?#column-sizing

Comment: I dont understand the confusion. `col-xs-2` etc takes up exactly the space you would expect, even if you dynamically change the width of the container -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cy0kx44o/171/**

Comment: From my understanding, I thought `col-xs-2` is only met when the screen is small?  And let's say it's big it should take up the whole the whole column and the succeeding columns are moved to a new line (?)

Comment: I don't understand why it's still small when `col-xs-2` is ONLY meant when the screen is below 768px. Unless I'm understanding it wrong

Comment: No, it is only met if you use it in conjunction with other grid classes. For example `class="col-xs-2 col-md-9 col-lg-12"` would give different layout on different screen widths, but if you only define `col-xs-2` then the element *always* will have apx `16.66%` width regardless of the screen width,

Comment: Okay I get it now. I just reread Grid Option (https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/css/?#grid-options) part in the documentation and I saw an example where `col-md-<number>` is defined and it took up the whole 12 column. Turns out if it's `xs` and the other ones starts to stack after they go above the breakpoint, it's grid behavior stays horizontal at all times. Thank you @davidkonrad

Comment: Could you write that as an answer so I can mark it? @davidkonrad